# Should these questions on file recovery be merged?

Tags: discussion

- [How to recover raw files from formatted SD card?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/38807/how-to-recover-raw-files-from-formatted-sd-card)
- [How can I recover deleted photos from an SD Card?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/how-can-i-recover-deleted-photos-from-an-sd-card)

One question has "RAW" files explicitly noted, the other has "deleted" photos explicitly noted.

Do we need both? Should the two questions and answers be merged? If I was using Google to answer a question would it make sense to show both results? Does it make sense to keep the term "SD Card" in the titles?

Answer (score 5):

Deleted and formatted are slightly, but significantly, different scenario's.  I'm not sure that it's exactly a duplicate.  The odds of success are far better if simply deleted and simpler software can often be used.  I think that's probably enough distinction to keep them separate.

Comment: I didn't vote to close the new one as a duplicate because RAW _is_ a special case. It does happen that any current data recovery software will cover that case, though.